# More than one image leads to no images displaying

Tags: media, navigation

I am running Drupal 7 with the 'Simple Corporate' theme by Devsaran.

I am trying to display several images on my front page with links attached to them. I tried using Image Link Formatter and although I seemed to have it all set up OK, no images displayed with or without links. So I have tried to fall back on using HTML in the body of the page but I am coming across some strange behaviour. If I put in one linked image, e.g.:

```
<a href='http://www.hp.com/UK' title='HP UK' target='_blank'>  <img class="fronticon" src='sites/all/themes/corporate/images/fronticons/partnerlogo.jpg' alt='HP Business Partner logo'> </a>
```

The image appears and clicking on it opens the link in a new page, as you would expect. However, if I add a second image, e.g.:

```
<a href='http://www.hp.com/UK' title='HP UK' target='_blank'>  <img class="fronticon" src='sites/all/themes/corporate/images/fronticons/partnerlogo.jpg' alt='HP Business Partner logo'> </a>
<a href='http://www.veeam.com' title='VEEAM' target='_blank'>  <img class="fronticon" src='sites/all/themes/corporate/images/fronticons/ProPartner_silver.png' alt='VEEAM Silver Pro Partner logo'> </a>
```

then nothing appears at all. Commenting out the second link has no effect, but removing it entirely allows the first image to reappear.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: _Commenting out the second link has no effect, but removing it entirely allows the first image to reappear._ I'm afraid that makes literally no sense, unless you have a weird browser extension messing with stuff. To the browser rendering engine, a commented out piece of HTML and a missing piece of HTML are exactly the same thing - not there. Actually I guess it could be CSS/JavaScript too, in theory at least, but someone with access to the codebase would need to search for that

Comment: I know it makes no sense but this is what I am seeing. I checked again just now by copying and pasting the first link below itself, saving and exiting - no images. Then I went back into the page, commented out the second link, saved and exited - no images. I then went back into the page again, removed the second link, saved and exited - the first link appeared on the page. Crazy, I know.

Comment: On the weird browser extension possibility, I am running Firefox and have now removed all extensions but this has not made any change.

Comment: On the CSS/javascript front, can anybody give me an idea of what I would be looking for?